# How can an object implements the Event interface in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

In this [.addEventListener in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

> **listener**
>
> The object that receives a notification (an object that implements the Event interface) when an event of the specified type occurs. This must be an object implementing the EventListener interface, or simply a JavaScript function.

It says we can use `an object that implements the Event interface` as listener for the event.

But I can't find how can object to implement the Event interface. As I tried:

```js
document.querySelector('#demo').addEventListener('click', {
  handleEvent: function (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}, false)
```

```css
#demo {
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="demo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This one can handle click event right.

Maybe you can give me some documents about this.

Comment: What is your question? You have declared a correct object with properly named interface function, and your code is working. It is exactly what "implements interface" means in JavaScript. **Duck typing:** If is has a function named `handleEvent`, then it implements `Event` interface.

Comment: `I can't find how can object to implement the Event interface` - yet you then post some code, which works, and you say `This one can handle click event right.` ... so, voilà - you've found an object that implements it

Comment: @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev Thanks, from I was reading source code of iScroll, I begin know this way to write event listener.As you know, we can write lots of functions in object, so when I give the `addEventListener` the object that contains many functions, the dispatch event will trigger which one?

Comment: yes, it will do that

Comment: @Jaromanda X  Thanks. So is there any documents about set object in addEventListener?

Comment: @TomIsion It will trigger the one with name `handleEvent` regardless of what other functions or members this object has. Exactly according to interface :)

Comment: @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev Cool, this make the `addEventListener` more fascinating. After all, I can't found some related info about this. Could you give me some knowledge about this?

Comment: Are you trying to attach an event to a plain object?

Comment: @guest271314 No, as we all know, we can give the `function` to the `addEventListener` to handle the event. From the mozilla, we can give the `object` too. So I wanna some info about the rquirement of the `object`. But I cannot find something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At [DOM](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/)

```
callback interface EventListener {
  void handleEvent(Event event);
};
```

is described at [IDL Index](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-index), which links to [3.6. Interface EventTarget](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-eventtarget), mentioned again at [3.8. Dispatching events](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dispatching-events)

> To [inner invoke](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-listener-inner-invoke) an object with event, run these steps: [Call a
>   user object’s operation](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#call-a-user-objects-operation) with listener’s callback, "`handleEvent`", a
>   list of arguments consisting of event, and event’s currentTarget
>   attribute value as the callback this value. If this throws an
>   exception, report the exception.
>
> An event listener can be used to observe a specific event.
>
> An event listener consists of these fields:
>
> - **type** (a string)
> - **callback** (an EventListener)
> - **capture** (a boolean, initially false)
> - **passive** (a boolean, initially false)
> - **once** (a boolean, initially false)
> - **removed** (a boolean for bookkeeping purposes, initially false)
>
> *Although callback is an [EventListener](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#callbackdef-eventlistener), as can be seen from the
>   fields above, an event listener is a broader concept.*

which references back to the `EventListener` object where `handleEvent` is the only named property.

```
callback interface EventListener {
  void handleEvent(Event event);
}
```

---

[Web IDL](https://heycam.github.io/webidl) clarifies

> [2.2. Interfaces](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-interfaces)
>
> The definition of `EventListener` as a callback interface is an
>   example of an existing API that needs to allow user objects with a
>   given property (in this case "`handleEvent`") to be considered to
>   implement the interface. For new APIs, and those for which there are
>   no compatibility concerns, using a callback function will allow only a
>   Function object (in the ECMAScript language binding).

> [`callback interface`](https://heycam.github.io/webidl)
>
> A callback interface is an interface that uses the callback keyword at
>   the start of its definition. Callback interfaces are ones that can be
>   implemented by [user objects](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-objects) and not by platform objects, as
>   described in §2.10 Objects implementing interfaces.
>
> ```
>     callback interface identifier {
>       /* interface_members... */
>     };
> ```
>
> [2.10. Objects implementing interfaces](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-objects)
>
> [User objects](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-user-object) are those that authors would create, implementing
>   callback interfaces that the Web APIs use to be able to invoke
>   author-defined operations or to send and receive values to the
>   author’s program through manipulating the object’s attributes. In a
>   web page, an ECMAScript object that implements the EventListener
>   interface, which is used to register a callback that the DOM Events
>   implementation invokes, would be considered to be a user object.
>
> Note that user objects can only implement callback interfaces and
>   platform objects can only implement non-callback interfaces.

For example

```
document.querySelector('#demo').addEventListener('click', {
  abc: function (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}, false)
```

does not dispatch event to `abc` handler. Though `handleEvent` identifier does dispatch event.