# Object.create inheritance and initialization code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code that defines a class for input events management: mouse, touch, pointer, ...

```
// base.js
export default () => {
  return {
    el: undefined,
    event: undefined,
    handler(ev) {
      console.log('default handler')
    },
    attach() {
      el.addEventListener(event, this.handler.bind(this), false)
    },
    detach() {
      el.removeEventListener(event, this.handler.bind(this), false)
    }
  }
}

// mouse.js
import baseInput from './base'

export default (el) => {
  return Object.assign(Object.create(baseInput()), {
    el: undefined,
    event: 'mousedown',
    handler(ev) {
      console.log('mouse handler)
    }
  }
}
```

There's some common business logic in 'base' object.

The problem comes from the calls to `this.handler.bind(this)` in `attach` and `detach` functions, because the returned bound function is not the same for each call, so `removeEventListener` can't remove the event listener added by `addEventListener`.

I know I have to keep one single function reference. My question is where that code should be.

One solution may be:

```
// base.js
export default () => {

  let boundFunction;

  return {
    el: undefined,
    event: undefined,
    getBoundFunction() {
      if (!boundFunction) {
        boundFunction = this.handler.bind(this)
      }
    },
    handler(ev) {
      console.log('default handler')
    },
    attach() {
      el.addEventListener(event, this.getBoundFunction(), false)
    },
    detach() {
      el.removeEventListener(event, this.getBoundFunction(), false)
    }
  }
}
```

This code works, but I don't want that extra `getBoundFunction` call for each event triggered and I think there should be a better method or best practice.

Comment: This is a very weird and somewhat wasteful way to do inheritance as you create a new base object, copy all its properties to a new object and then throw it way.  Why are you doing inheritance this way?  You can just extend the base object with your new properties/methods rather than copying and throwing it away.

Comment: There must be a typo in your first code block because in `mouse.js`, you have two consecutive `return` statements.

Comment: Yes. There's a typo. Thanks. Fixed!

Comment: About the inheritance, I wrote just the relevant lines to show the problem with bindings, but the base code is quite larger and is using some in-closure variables and methods. But I'll review it.

Comment: "*I think there should be a better method or best practice.*" - the best practice for object creation with inheritance and initialisation code (which in your case would be `this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)`) is to use constructors and `new`. Of course you could do the same and just bind your handler method the factory function.

Answer (score 3):

Implement the event listener interface by changing the name of `handler` to `handleEvent`. Then you just bind the object directly.

The value of `this` in the `handleEvent` function will be the bound object.

```
// base.js
export default () => {
  return {
    el: undefined,
    event: undefined,
    handleEvent(ev) {
      console.log('default handler')
    },
    attach() {
      el.addEventListener(event, this, false)
    },
    detach() {
      el.removeEventListener(event, this, false)
    }
  }
}
```

So then objects that inherit from the base object can define their own `handleEvent` function, which will get called when the bound events fire.

---

Also, you seem to be creating a new base object for each object that inherits from it. Why not share a base object? That's the point of prototypal inheritance.

Comment: This is a seldom used trick.  If you pass an object to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`, it looks for a special property name called `handleEvent` and calls it with the context of the original object.  Odd, but works.

Comment: @jfriend00: You're right. I think people just don't know about it. It does a nice job of unifying business logic and objects with event handling. Makes for well-organized code, IMO.

Comment: fwiw [How can an object implements the Event interface in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353746/how-can-an-object-implements-the-event-interface-in-javascript/)

Comment: Interesting tip! I didn't know about it. But the problem with the Event interface is that my code is part or a library and should support three ways of attaching events: el.addEventListener, el.attachEvent (IE10) and el["on{eventName}"]